# Workbench TestSuite problem

Tags: workbench, testing-and-verification

I am working on an application using Workbench 3.0 and Mathematica 10.4.0. I've written a couple of test files for different parts of my work, and a master file with a test suite:

```
TestSuite[
    {
        FileNameJoin[{"ExternalFunctions", "GCS_routines", "GCSroutines.mt"}]
        ,
        FileNameJoin[{"TestCases", "SphericalHarmonics.mt"}]
        ,
        FileNameJoin[{"TestCases", "IgesRead.mt"}]
    }
]
```

Now, if I run the test suite, the resulting output is not as neatly structured as it is shown in workbench help. I get the following:

[image: Wolfram Unit Tester output]

Just a flat list, and even worse, the single results are no longer linked to the test cases, clicking them doesn't work.

Running a single test file works as expected.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your use of `FileNameJoin` seems to trip up the unit tester. If you just use `"TestCases/IgesRead.mt"` etc, it should work (I think `/` gets accepted as a path separator on Windows as well but not sure)

Comment: @Gerli, you were absolutely right. And `/` works as path separator on Windows. If you post your comment as an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `FileNameJoin` seems to trip up the unit tester (this is a bug).

A workaround is to just use `/` as a path separator in the string (works on OSX, Linux, and Windows):

```
TestSuite[
    {
        "ExternalFunctions/GCS_routines/GCSroutines.mt"
        ,
        "TestCases/SphericalHarmonics.mt"
        ,
        "TestCases/IgesRead.mt"
    }
]
```